# Wordpress Child Theme Override Parent Theme Class

Tags: themes, app-themes, wordpress

I am using Hirebee theme downloaded from Appthemes. I have successfully created its child theme and I am able to modify files in the root.

Now, I want to edit files placed inside `hirebee/includes/some-file.php` but I am not able to edit the same.

I have tried the with having same structure in my child theme but that didn't help. I have tried using require_once for including that same file in my child theme but returns me a blank page.

I want to know how we can extend parent theme classes in hirebee's case or any other way I can use to override those specific subfolders files.

Answer (score -2):

There're multiple mandatory things to do for a child theme to be effective.

I suggest you to check the Wordpress documentation as I can't see what missing after reading your issue :

https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: Can you please suggest something else. I have already gone through this documentation.